Is there an error in this derivation of the bias-variance tradeoff formula?
I am wondering if this is a mistake on Wikipedia or if I have misunderstood something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff They have the Bias-Variance tradeoff formula here:

I am wondering about something in the start of the derivation. I will post a picture here, note that this is just the start of the derivation, there is more, but I am only including the relevant part:

I am wondering about what they say that $x$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent. Isn't $x$ a fixed quantity? Regarding the post by Alecos Papadopoulos here: Predictor and error are independent isn't so that $\hat{f}(x)$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent because $\hat{f}$ is based on the training data, but $x$ is a fixed quantity? In the post by Xavier Bourret Sicotte here: Understanding bias-variance tradeoff derivation he calculates $E[ (Y - \hat f(x_0) )^2 | X = x_0]$, here we see that $x_0$ is constant.
So does Wikipedia have a random $x$ or is it wrong? Should it say that $\hat{f}(x)$ is independent of $\varepsilon$ instead of $x$ is independent of $\varepsilon$? Or does it work when $x$ is random? Do you agree that we fix $x$ in the formula?

I think their notation is not as stringent as it could be. x is a sample of the random variable X ... (So yes for a given Dataset it will be fixed). Maybe some expert here wants to make the notation more stringent

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656503
