Variance-bias tradeoff formula for simple linear regression with both X fixed and X random
I am trying to understand the Variance-Bias tradeoff formula using simple linear regression. But there are some formulas I am not able to derive. I will explain what I mean by first doing it for a fixed $X$ and then for a random $X$. Here is the Bias-Variance tradeoff formula:

1. Simple linear regression with fixed $X$.
I assume the model is $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is $N(0,\sigma^2)$. I assume I have $k$ x-values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$, that are fixed, and I observe $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_k$.
Define $S_{xy}=\sum_{j=1}^k (x_j-\overline{x})(y_j-\overline{y}), S_{xx}=\sum_{j=1}^k (x_j-\overline{x})^2$.
From elementary statistics we have the the least square estimators are:
$\hat{\beta_1}=\frac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}}, \hat{\beta_0}=\overline{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\overline{x}.$
Assume you want to observe a new observation at a point $x^*$. We then have
$\hat{f}(x^*)=\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x^*$. In elementary statistics texts it is shown that $E[\hat{f}(x^*)]=E[\hat{\beta_0}+\hat{\beta_1}x^*]=\beta_0+\beta_1x^*=f(x^*)$.
It is also shown than $V(\hat{f}(x^*))=\sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(\overline{x}-x^*)^2}{S_{xx}}\right)$.
Question: Do you then agree that the bias-variance tradeoff formula become:
$E((Y^*-\hat{f}(x^*))^2)=\sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(\overline{x}-x^*)^2}{S_{xx}}\right)+0+\sigma^2$?
Have I in this case made the correct assumptions about what is done in linear regression?
2. Simple linear regression with random $X$.
Assume still that $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1 X+\epsilon$, also assume that $\epsilon$ and $X$ are independent. Also assume that $X\text{~} N(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$. Assume now that you observe $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_k,y_k)$. And you create $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ as above to create $\hat{f}$. Assume you also fix the point $x^*$. What is now $E((Y^*-\hat{f}(x^*))^2)$? Note, it can't be what it was above, because the points $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are not fixed, but the formulas depends on them(for example $S_{xx}$), but $E((Y^*-\hat{f}(x^*))^2)$ should still exist?

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/656499

1. Fixed $X$
Assuming that the expression you wrote for $\text{Var}(\hat f(x^*)) = \text{Var}(\hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 x^*)$ is correct (I haven't checked and I don't know off the top of my head), that bias-variance tradeoff looks correct to me, since OLS is unbiased. Usually in the expositions you find in "elementary statistics textbooks" one assumes that $x_1, \dots, x_k$  are fixed. With that said, in other fields (particularly econ/econometrics) people like random design matrices.
2. Random $X$
If you follow the proofs that you mentioned in the first section, but replace all the expectations with conditional expectations, conditioning on $X$, you can actually see that they go through exactly the same (under the assumption of independence between $\epsilon$ and $X$). In fact, in general, OLS with fixed data is the same as taking OLS with random data and independent residuals and conditioning on the data (cf. this CV post).
Then, all the formulas derived are valid conditional on $X$ taking on values $x_1, \dots, x_k$, i.e. what is true is
$$
E[(Y^* - \hat f(x^*)^2 \mid x_1, \dots, x_n] = \{ \text{ the expression in the first section } \}.
$$
Then, if you want the unconditional MSE for a new point $x^*$, you may simply take an outer expectation, by the tower rule, i.e.
$$
E[E[(Y^* - \hat f(x^*)^2 \mid x_1, \dots, x_n]]  = E[(Y^* - \hat f(x^*)^2]
$$
where the outer expectation is over the random data. If your data distribution is complicated, this expectation might be analytically intractable.

Your first computation is a conditional expectation value. Using the law of total expectation you can find the unconditional expectation value by integrating or summing over all conditions.
If $X$ is a discrete variable
$$E[Y] = \sum_{\forall X} E[Y|X] p(X)$$
If $X$ is a continuous variable with $d\mu$ the probability measure
$$E[Y] = \int_{\forall X} E[Y|X] d \mu(X)$$
In your case it relates to the distribution of the variable
$$\frac{(\overline{x}-x^*)^2}{S_{xx}}$$
this is a ratio distribution and can be very tricky as the expectation value might be infinite or undefined. That is when $S_{xx}$ has a non-zero density in the point $S_{xx} = 0$. At the same time, the equation for the estimation breakes down, because when $S_{xx} = 0$ it is not that your estimate has a variance with a division by zero, but it is not possible to make any estimate at all.

Another issue, the bias doesn't have to be zero for linear regression. It happens when the model is misspecified. An example is

from Why is the intercept in multiple regression changing when including/excluding regressors?

If the x are standard normal distributed, then the ratio distribution relates to a F-distribution and, the distribution of $S_{xx}$ is zero for a large enough number of observations. In that case the expectation value is defined and finite. I believe that there is a question about this (something like "intuition why the F distribution has a defined moment when the degrees of freedom is larger?")

I think it was this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600947

This question and comment as well https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299722/ive-heard-that-ratios-or-inverses-of-random-variables-often-are-problematic-in/299730#comment1069124_299765
